# Postman :How to Save only part of Header response as Environment Valuable

Tags: parsing, text, environment-variables, postman

I'm trying to save a sliced part of a token that is returned by the response of an API call; the token is overturned in the header 
`oiasdjiasjoij|1233` I just need the part before the `|` only the `oiasdjiasjoij` without the `1233`.

I've used the code below

```
pm.environment.set( "Val2",pm.response.headers.get('token'));
```

but it saves the whole value, and I need only part of it.

```
Token = oiasdjiasjoij|1233
```

I need `oiasdjiasjoij` to save as parameter.

Comment: Please share which language are you working with if that's needed. For example, I don't know if I can share a **Regular Expression** solution for you or not.

Comment: if postman support Regular Expression , cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Postman uses internally JavaScript you can use its function `string.split(divider)`, which produces an array of strings divided by your `divider`

Try this:

```
pm.environment.set("Val2", pm.response.headers.get('token').split('|')[0]);
```

Here we splitting your token by `|` character and use the very first element of resulting array `[0]`

There is one little trick though, if you will not have an `|` in your token you will have full token value as the result. Because `split()` will return an array with just one element.

Comment: This seems like a simple answer for your question. As the Question has been asked by a new contributor, It might be worth explaining what's actually happening in the `.split()` function.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciated, it will help others when they stumble on a similar problem. :)